# 3D desktop application with Blender

Tags: python

I'm currently in the process of looking for the best tool to develop an application. Based on the following specification, I'd love to hear from you blender experts whether it's the right framework for my project.

- I'd like to export the final product as both a .exe and .app file.
- It's not a game but rather a mesh utility tool.
- I'll be doing a lot of mesh modifications, solving intersections between planes and meshes - for example.
- I'll need a UI for user
- I'm proficient in Python.
- I'll need tools such as Pandas, scipy and numpy.
- I'll need to import/export 3D file.
- All of the above will be required in final desktop app.

If Blender sounds like a plausible candidate, could you point me towards the modules I should be using (for mesh, UI...)? Any limitations I should be aware of?

If not, do you know an alternative?

Comment: You should maybe ask your question on https://devtalk.blender.org/ , it's basically the forum where Blender's devs (and addons devs) are visiting on a daily basis. There are the people that do know Blender on the dev side and might even be able to help you with Blender's python API.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm developing a web application that allows architects to load their models in a-frame (their models are decimated, processed and texture's are baked). I've been initially using c4d for this but I had a big limitation: I couldn't include python packages (I needed numpy). Then I decided to move to blender and It's working nicely.

I don't actually know how you could include blender in a .exe or .app file, but since blender it's open source and multi-platform, you should not have big problems. You'll probably have to download the repo from git and do some tweaking.

Since you will have to solve a lot of equations, you could consider using libigl https://libigl.github.io/ 
It's actually a header-only library (in C++ with a python interface) so you could actually use it along with blender, if you want to. I haven't done it, but I'm coding a mesh decimation algorithm with libigl to be include in blender (for academic purpose)

Hope this helped

Comment: This is very interesting to me, could you say a few words on the architecture of your app? What do you use for the front-end, where does blender reside...?

Comment: @Charles.fried Sure. The webapp is a drag n drop: you drag the 3d file you want to render in VR and it gets rendered. How does this work? On the client side, it sends the 3d file to the server. The server receives the file and opens blender as subprocess giving a python script. This python does some stuff with the geometries and materials. When this is finished blender exports a glb into a folder, and the server sends this back to the client. This is a bit different from what you want to do, still, you could take some inspiration. I can't explain everything in detail in one comment...